# What is this piece of code doing?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I got this from 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1

Basically it relates to the login process

```
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"))
        .setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
```

Why does facebook check if a session is not opened(closed i am assuming) and the session is not closed(assuming its open then)?

Won't this conditional statement always evaluate to false?

Comment: if session = null, wont that be a null pointer exception?

Comment: Why not just check session is not null?

Comment: like from logic wise, i think this is always going to evaluate to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the [source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/SessionState.java), you'll notice that `isOpened()` and `isClosed()` are not logical complements of each other but just two distinct state enumeration values the session can be in.

Comment: Logic wise, wouldn't it make more sense to just check that the session  " the state represents a successfully opened state in which the Session can be used with a {@link Request}"(docs you sent me) so you can set the correct permissions?